# How to Redirect to Home Page Using JQuery-UI Dialog?

Tags: jquery-ui-dialog, dotnetnuke-5

I'm using the following JQuery block in my DotNetNuke module:

```
jquery(document).ready(function (){
      $( "#dialog:ui-dialog").dialog("destroy");
      $( "#dialog-message").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function(){
                $( this ).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
});
</script>
<div id="dialog-message" title="Registration Confirmed">
```

I'm not sure how to redirect the user to the home page when they click the Ok button?  Also, how do I wire up the dialog-message DIV to only fire when my ASP:Button is clicked?

Thanks much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put an **OnClientClick** on your Button and call a function that will show your modal. When the ok button is clicked you can change the **window.location** to the path of your homepage.

**HTML**

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btn_ShowModal" OnClientClick="showModal(); return false;" />
```

**Javascript**

```
function showModal()
{
    $( "#dialog-message").dialog({
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function(){
                $( this ).dialog("close");
                window.location = "pathToHomepage";
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit**
There are two types of paths that can be used in javascript and in web development in general: relative paths and absolute paths.

**Relative paths**: start from the current directory and you access the desired location from there using '**/**' to go forward a directory and '**../**' to go backward

**Absolute paths**: the full url to the desired location

You can find a more thorough description [here](http://www.boogiejack.com/server_paths.html)

'**~/**' is a sever side "shortcut" that unfortunately does not work on the client side without using something like **[this.ResolveClientUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl.aspx)**.

```
'<%= this.ResolveClientUrl("~/default.aspx") %>'
```

Comment: May I use ~/default.aspx as pathToHomepage?  Or is it advisable to put in the full URL?  Thanks:)

Comment: Yes, this worked perfectly. Thanks for taking the time to respond. Much appreciated:)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowPopup(message) {
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog").html(message);
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                title: "Alert",
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        window.location = "home.aspx";
                    }
                },
                modal: true
            });
        });
    };
</script>
```

client side

```
         string message = "Profile Updated!!.";
         ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup('" + message + "');", true);
```